# Bluez core interferes with HCI socket commands

Tags: sockets, bluetooth, bluez, hci, pybluez

I have following problem: I have created a HCI socket via pybluez and try to create a connection to a remote device. I send successfully a CREATE_CONNECTION command but after receiving the answers it seems the bluez stack sends further requests automatically like "Read Remote Supported Features".(visible in the wireshark traces of the HCI communication)
I wanna have full and exclusive control over the bluetooth controller.
I have also tried to stop the bluetooth service but the bluez stack still send automatically requests.

Any hints or tips how to solve this issue?

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing and found the solution. Basically you need to bind your socket with the

```
hci_channel=HCI_USER_CHANNEL
```

Check this link for more information:
[Direct Control of HCI Device (Bypass Bluetooth Drivers) on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703507/direct-control-of-hci-device-bypass-bluetooth-drivers-on-linux)